Converting MySQL MyISAM longtext to Innodb
I am belatedly converting some php applications using MySQL from MyISAM to Innodb.  One set of tables were converted on Friday, and now on Monday there are problems.  Specifically for one table used to store session information, using in MyISAM a longtext field. The problem is that some session information isn't being written into the data.  Initial data makes it in, but later data does not.  Seems to be data length related?  I have compared the table structure from identical apps (different data) from one that works, and one that doesn't, and I don't observe any differences.
Anyone have experience with this?

Longtext should be able to store up to 4GB. Granted, if you use a multi-byte character set, you may be limited to 1 billion characters, but if your session data is that long, your application is... let's call it atypical. :-)

If you can SHOW CREATE TABLE to show the exact definition of the table, and show a value that reproduces the problem, that would help. Best if you can make a dbfiddle to make it reproducible. And if you're getting an error message, please include that in your post above.

While there might be some subtle problem with the longtext field, one significant difference between innodb and myisam is transactions. These can have the effect, that if you e.g. insert 5 rows at a time, and the last row has an error, for myisam, you end up with 4 rows, and with innodb, you end up with 0 rows. Should throw an error in your app, so you should check there. Similarly, the innodb settings might be different, e.g. strict mode for transactions, which might disallows some invalid values, so the problem might not be the longtext, but e.g. an incorrect date.

Thanks!  Here's the results of SHOW CREATE TABLE from a database that works, vs the one that doesn't.
I'm pretty sure I can just drop the troublesome table and replace it with the CREATE TABLE from the one that works and go on my merry way, but it would be good to know what the actual problem is. Something to do with all the "collate" stuff?

Works:
CREATE TABLE session_info (
sessid varchar(40) NOT NULL,
ipaddr varchar(32) NOT NULL,
lastused datetime DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
uid int(11) DEFAULT '0',
remember tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
vars longtext NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (sessid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Doesn't work: CREATE TABLE session_info ( sessid varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, ipaddr varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, lastused datetime DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00', uid int(11) DEFAULT '0', remember tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', vars longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (sessid) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

Alas, it didn't work. The tables are now identical but the one that didn't work still doesn't work.  I have tried innodb_strict_mode = off and it didn't help.

"The problem is that some session information isn't being written into the data. Initial data makes it in, but later data does not." -- Elaborate.

Thanks.  It's a session data table, so info regarding the user's session gets added to the field as the user does things on the site.  So when the session starts, it gets it's initial minimal data.  However the next action is often to log in, authenticated against an OpenID server.  After the user submits the login form, some authentication data is saved to the session record before the user is redirected to the OpenID server. At least that's what is supposed to happen.  This data isn't being saved. So when control returns, it fails to match and login fails.
